# PhotoshopCC Dropping frames on image sequence export

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, video

I have been kind of tearing my hair out trying to figure this out. I have a frame animation with 30 frames. I tried exporting it as a video set to 12fps. For some reason, what should be 2.5 seconds (30 frames at 12fps) is dropping down to 2 seconds on export. I thought it was some weird video codec glitch, but I discovered that the same thing happens when I export as an image sequence: Even though I have checked several times that "All Frames" was selected (other options are disabled anyway), I find only 24 pngs in my sequence where there should be 30.

Any help with this? It's a frame-by-frame rotoscoped animation so switching from frame animation to a timeline animation doesn't quite work. I know I can export frames manually by saving each frame one at a time, but it would be lovely to not have to do that (or to find a script that can do this for me to save time).

I'll gladly share screenshots later tonight when I'm at my animation computer again.

Comment: Can you try to make the total number of frames to 36 or drop it to perfect 24? 
I'm not so sure though.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you don’t make a 12 fps video, which is a very odd setting and that is probably why you have run into some kind of bug. Use a standard video frame rate like 24 fps or 30 fps. Since your animation is already 30 fps, you should use 30 fps.

The video you create out of Photoshop is not a shareable video, it is a master. It should be the highest quality that you can make. Full-size, full frame rate. Then you take your master video and you put it through a video encoder to create sharable copies for various bandwidths and screen sizes.

For example, you might open the master video in QuickTime Player and export 1080p, 720p, and 480p sharable copies. The video encoder will optimize the sharable copies by compressing frames and by combining parts of frames that are similar. You don’t need to pre-optimize by reducing your frame rate. The video encoder works best if it gets the full frame rate to work with.